# Do I need to unsubscribe?

Tags: c#, .net, events, lambda, anonymous-function

I have the following code:

```
public void UnPublishDatabases(IReadOnlyCollection<IPublishedDatabase> sqlDatabases)
{
    var listener = new UnpublishDatabaseListener();
    listener.DatabaseUnpublished += db =>
    {
        OnDatabaseUnpublished(db); 
        listener.DatabaseUnpublished -= OnDatabaseUnpublished;
    };

    _publishController.Unpublish(sqlDatabases, listener);
    //...
}
```

And diagnostic processor gives me the following warning:

```
Event 'listener.DatabaseUnpublished' should not be subscribed with the same 'listener.DatabaseUnpublished' object.
```

So I try to understand what is wrong here.
And try to find how to change the code.

Probably it solves the warning:

```
public void UnPublishDatabases(IReadOnlyCollection<IPublishedDatabase> sqlDatabases)
{
    var listener = new UnpublishDatabaseListener();
    //save ref
    var listenerCopy = listener;
    listener.DatabaseUnpublished += db =>
    {
        OnDatabaseUnpublished(db); 
        //use it
        listenerCopy.DatabaseUnpublished -= OnDatabaseUnpublished;
    };

    _publishController.Unpublish(sqlDatabases, listener);
    //...
}
```

Also I have a question - do I really need to unsubscribe here ?
Because listener is just a local object.

### UPD:

```
public class UnpublishDatabaseListener
{
    public event Action<IPublishedDatabase> DatabaseUnpublished;
    //...
}
```

Comment: are those custom types? I am not familiar

Comment: yes. they are custom types

Comment: I am also confused with the calls being made in the handler. Can you show the relevant `UnpublishDatabaseListener` members related to this problem.

Comment: side note: `var listenerCopy = listener;` as you said a **copy**, does this mean, that `UnpublishDatabaseListener` is a struct?

Comment: @Nkosi i've updated my code

Comment: @vasily.sib no, it's a class. see my comment which sad save ref

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the delegate in a variable so that it can be used to subscribe and unsubscribe in the lambda handler.

```
public void UnPublishDatabases(IReadOnlyCollection<IPublishedDatabase> sqlDatabases) {
    var listener = new UnpublishDatabaseListener();
    Action<IPublishedDatabase> handler = delegate { };
    handler = db => {
        OnDatabaseUnpublished(db); 
        //unsubscribe
        listner.DatabaseUnpublished -= handler;
    };
    //subscribe
    listener.DatabaseUnpublished += handler;

    _publishController.Unpublish(sqlDatabases, listener);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Ok, let me try this approach. By the way what is the difference between using lambda and delegate ?

Comment: @isxaker I put the delegate there just so the handler wont be  *null*. I could have just as easily declared `Action<IPublishedDatabase> handler = null;`. Want to make sure the variable is assigned. would have gotten a syntax error otherwise. It's a pattern I picked up a while back.

Comment: yes of course i now how to do that )) but my questions is what the difference between using lambda and named delegate ?  I mean probably the delegate's body will be created immediately with actual reference on listener. And if lambda is used what wrong with that ?

Comment: I'm thinking, the reference to the lambda. having the variable give a hard reference to refer to.